# how to update uploaded file yii2

Tags: yii2

controller-

```
public function actionUpdate($id) { 
    $model = $this->findModel($id); 
    $model->scenario = 'update'; 
    if ($this->request->isPost) { 
       if ($model->load($this->request->post())) { 
          $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image'); 
          $fileName = time().'.'. $model->image->extension; 
          $model->image->saveAs('uploads/'. $fileName); 
          $model->image = $fileName; 
          $model->save(); 
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); 
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 use yii\web\UploadedFile;
  public function actionUpdate($id) { 
  $model = $this->findModel($id); 
  if ($this->request->isPost) { 
    if ($model->load($this->request->post())) { 
       $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
       if ( $model->image ){
          //rename the image
          $model->image->saveAs('upload/' .$model->id. '.' . $model->image->extension);

          //save the name image to database
          $model->image = 'upload/' .$model->id. '.' . $model->image->extension;
       }
     }
  }
```

}

if you want to keep the old file
add specification , example date now

```
$model->image->saveAs('upload/' .$model->id.'.'.date("Y-m-d").'.' $model->image->extension);
```

Comment: it didnt work-  if ( $model->image ){
          //rename the image
          $model->image->saveAs('upload/' .$model->id. '.' . $model->image->extension);

          //save the name image to database
          $model->image = 'upload/' .$model->id. '.' . $model->image->extension;
       }